# Assign unique identifier for dataframe rows based on dataframe with preassigned unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, uniqueidentifier

I have dataframe with unique identifier assigned based on three columns i.e., [col2,col3,col3]

Dataframe1:

```
col1      col2     col3     col4      col5         unique_id
1         abc       bcv      zxc      www.com        8
2         bcd       qwe      rty      www.@com       12
3         klp       oiu      ytr      www.io         15
4         zxc       qwe      rty      www.com        6
```

After data preprocessing, will import Dataframe_2 with same column values as shown above but without unique_id. Dataframe_2 rows must be assigned with unique identifier based on col2,col3,col4 and by referring to the Dataframe1.

If Dataframe_2 has new row which is not present in Dataframe1, then assign new identifier.

Dataframe_2:

```
col1      col2     col3     col4      col5         
1         bcd       qwe      rty      www.@com              
2         zxc       qwe      rty      www.com
3         abc       bcv      zxc      www.com 
4         kph       hir      mat      www.com
```

Expected Dataframe_2:

```
col1      col2     col3     col4      col5         unique_id        
1         bcd       qwe      rty      www.@com        12     
2         zxc       qwe      rty      www.com         6
3         abc       bcv      zxc      www.com         8 
4         kph       hir      mat      www.com         35
```

Since Row4 is not present in Dataframe1, a new unique identifier is assigned.

Comment: [col2,col3,col3] why duplicate col3 for datframe1?

Comment: what is the rule for assigning a new unique identifier for `Expected Dataframe_2`'s `row4`.

Comment: @Ferris For example If dataframe1's unique identifier ends at 30. then new identifier for Expected Dataframe_2's row4 would be 31

Comment: ok, I post an answer, hope it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# assign the old unique_id
df2n = df2.join(df1.set_index(['col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])[['unique_id']],
         on=['col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'], how='left')

# assign new unique_id with max df1.unique_id + 1
id_max = df1.unique_id.max() + 1
null_num = df2n['unique_id'].isnull().sum()

cond = df2n['unique_id'].isnull()
df2n.loc[cond,'unique_id'] = range(id_max, id_max + null_num)
df2n['unique_id'] = df2n['unique_id'].astype(int)

print(df2n)

      col1 col2 col3 col4      col5  unique_id
    0     1  bcd  qwe  rty  www.@com         12
    1     2  zxc  qwe  rty   www.com          6
    2     3  abc  bcv  zxc   www.com          8
    3     4  kph  hir  mat   www.com         16
```

Answer (score 0):

First add column `unique_id` by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join `on` parameter is omitted for merge by columns `['col2','col3','col4']` specified in subset. For not matched values are created missing values, so is used [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) for test them and `np.arange` for create new array after maximal value and assign them in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df = Dataframe_2.merge(Dataframe_1[['col2','col3','col4', 'unique_id']],
                       how='left')

mask = df['unique_id'].isna()
maximal = Dataframe_1['unique_id'].max() + 1

df.loc[mask, 'unique_id'] = np.arange(maximal, maximal + mask.sum())

df['unique_id'] = df['unique_id'].astype(int)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3 col4      col5  unique_id
0     1  bcd  qwe  rty  www.@com         12
1     2  zxc  qwe  rty   www.com          6
2     3  abc  bcv  zxc   www.com          8
3     4  kph  hir  mat   www.com         16
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['col2','col3','col4'], how='right')

def return_unique_num(df1):
  uniqueIds = list(df1['unique_id'].values)
  unique_num = random.randint(1,len(df1)+1)
  while True:
    if unique_num in uniqueIds:
      unique_num = random.randint(1,len(df1)+1)
    else:
      break
  return unique_num

for i, e in enumerate(df3['unique_id']):
  if math.isnan(e):
    df3.iloc[i, 5] = return_unique_num(df1) #replace nan value with unique integer in df3 unique_id column


df3['unique_id'] = df3['unique_id'].astype(int)

df2['unique_id'] = df3['unique_id']
```

It will assign unique IDs to df2 based on unique_id of df1

Output

```
col1      col2     col3     col4      col5         unique_id        
1         bcd       qwe      rty      www.@com        12     
2         zxc       qwe      rty      www.com         6
3         abc       bcv      zxc      www.com         8 
4         kph       hir      mat      www.com         35
```